# Completion block/callback on FetchRequest completion

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, callback, nsfetchrequest

I have a `FetchRequest` in my model class named `ContentManager`.  It fetches quite a lot of data, so the screen is blank until it's completion. In the `ViewController` that displays the fetched results, I would like to show a loading indicator, so I would like to get a callback when the `FetchRequest` has completed and pass that to the `ViewController` to stop the loading indicator. Is this possible?

Here is the `FetchRequest` from the `ContentManager` class:

```
- (NSArray*)recipesForMagazine
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recipe" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"magazine_recipe_guids" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray* recipeGuids = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"guid IN %@",recipeGuids];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor* sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [sort release];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    [request release];

    return fetchResults;        
}
```

Here I set it up in the `ViewController`

`self.magazineRecipes = [[ContentManager defaultManager] recipesForMagazine];`

I want to set up the fetchrequest method like this:

`- (NSArray*)recipesForMagazine:(void (^)(BOOL success))block` or something, so in the `viewcontroller` I can call it like this

```
self.magazineRecipes = [[CTContentManager defaultManager] recipesForMagazine:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        //stop activity indicator view
    }
}];
```

I don't know if I'm at all in the right way of thinking, thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the viewController a delegate of the `ContentManager` class. So in the `ContentManager.h` I would do something like:

```
    @protocol ContentManagerDelegate()
      -(void) didFetchResults:(NSArray *) results;
      -(void) didResultsFail: (NSError *) error;
    @end

    @interface ContentManager : <SuperClass Name>
    -(id) initWithDelegate: (id<ContentManagerDelegate>) delegate;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id<ContentManagerDelegate> delegate;
    @end
```

and in the implementation:

```
   -(id) initWithDelegate: (id<ContentManagerDelegate>) delegate
    {
        self = [super init];
        if(self)
        {
           _delegate = delegate;
         }
        return self;
    }
```

and in your `recipesForMagazine` method you can use the delegate `[_delegate didFetchResults: fetchResults]`, you can implement a method to pass errors to the delegate if you want as well. In your `ViewController.h` do `@interface ViewController.h : UIViewController <ContentManagerDelegate>` and in the implementation you should be able to implement the `didFetchResults:` method that will give you the results and in that method you can stop the activity indicator from animating.